# Android calculate screen size for draw

Tags: android, size, brush

I am trying to draw in my app, so I want my brush size be 10% of the device screen which means that for all device it should be diffrent size. 
I read in android developer guide [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about dp.

```
        getScreenSizeDpi();
        m_brushSize = (int)(area * brush_percentages)/100;
        circle_area = m_brushSize * m_brushSize * Math.PI;
}
```

And the method:

```
private void getScreenSizeDpi() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    area = dpHeight * dpWidth;
}
```

But all I want is to get the circle of the brush size, Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get the screen size if you are inside an `Activity`

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not inside an `Activity`, use this instead to obtain the `Display` object

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Then set the brush size

```
brush_size = 0.1 * width;// or 0.1 * height
```

Comment: No, I need the circle of the brush size, thanks anyway

Comment: if you need 10% of the area of the inscribed circle then you need something like this `0.1 * (Math.PI * Math.pow(Math.min(width, height), 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an update for compose

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSizedSquare() {
    val context = LocalContext.current.resources
    val displayMetrics = context.displayMetrics
    val screenWidth = (displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density).dp
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(shape = RectangleShape)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .width(screenWidth)
            .height(screenWidth)
    )
}
```